Is it possible to create canvas on a live video in the React native application
In react,we can draw a canvas at different points on the video can that be done in react native as well. I require to understand that similar manner we are able to work on the video in react can also be done in react native

yes, you could able to create canvas in react video stream with the help of the react library react-native-canvas
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';

const CanvasOverlay = ({ canvasRef }) => {
  const handleCanvas = (canvas) => {
    if (canvas) {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      // Perform drawing operations here
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }
  };

  return <Canvas ref={handleCanvas} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }} />;

};

Have you tried this on any live video?
